How can I prevent my homemade sauce from becoming too watery when frying vegetables?
When I fry vegetables to make a sauce, the water released from the vegetables often makes the sauce too watery. What techniques can I use to ensure my sauce maintains a thicker consistency while frying?

What vegetables are you frying? There may be specific techniques for them.  The rest of the process may be important, as there may be some step that’s a problem.  (Like cooking over high heat, instead of low heat and a wide pan so moisture had a chance to evaporate)

What kind of sauce are you making? I can think of many possibilities here. Are you putting pieces of vegetables in a pan and waiting for them to become very soft, and serving that as a chunky sauce? Or again starting with pieces of vegetables and softening, then pureeing? Or are you pureeing the vegetables raw, then cooking? Or are you making some other kind of sauce, say a roux-based one, and adding fried vegetables to that?

You have two basic options:

Thicken the sauce by reducing it (boiling off some of the water)
Thicken the sauce by adding a thickening agent to it

Which you prefer, and the details of how to achieve it, will depend on what you're cooking and how you want it to end up.


For resilient vegetables that you're not worried about overcooking (e.g., collard greens), you can just cook them for longer.  Water will gradually boil off the top of the cooking vessel (faster if you remove the lid), thickening and concentrating your sauce.  But, of course, the vegetables will also be cooking the entire time, so for more delicate vegetables, this can result in an overcooked end product.



For vegetables that you are worried about overcooking, you can simply remove the vegetables while you reduce the sauce:


Start with whatever steps need to happen prior to adding liquid (e.g., sautéing garlic)
Add your vegetables
Add your sauce
Wait for the vegetables to release their liquid, resulting in the too-wet situation you're trying to avoid, and cook them until they're a couple minutes short of done
Remove the vegetables
Simmer the sauce until it reaches your desired thickness
Add the vegetables back in for a couple minutes to heat them up and finish the last couple minutes of cooking



The final option is adding a thickener.  You can use many different things for this, which will all have somewhat different results, so you might need to experiment or read recipes for similar dishes to figure out what to use, but to list a few possibilities:


Mix a little water with corn starch and pour the resulting suspension into simmering sauce.  Stir constantly as you add the corn starch mixture, to avoid ending up with little clumps of corn starch goo.  This works well for soy-based Asian sauces, in my experience.
Prepare a roux of flour and butter and mix it into your sauce.  This works well for meaty sauces where you want the result to be gravy-like.
Experiment with the various gums and the like (xanthan gum, gum acacia, gelatin, pectin, agar, okra mucilage, etc.).  These all thicken things, but all have different results in terms of texture, so either use these as directed by a recipe, or commit to some trial-and-error (accepting that you might end up with some gross slime sauces while you're learning how they work).

